# How to merge two crystal reports into one in Delphi using TCrpe

Tags: delphi, pdf, crystal-reports, merge

I am absolutely new to Delphi and Crystal Reports.
I figured that I can export a crystal report to pdf like this:

```
crpe.Clear;
crpe.ReportName := 'CoverSheet.rpt';
crpe.ParamFields[0].CurrentValue := '0';
crpe.Output:=toExport;
crpe.ExportOptions.Destination:=toApplication;
crpe.ExportOptions.FileName:='C:\CoverSheet.pdf';
crpe.ExportOptions.FileType:=AdobeAcrobatPDF;
crpe.Export;
```

(Although this is working, please let me know if I am doing it wrong :) )

Now I have two .rpts "**CoverSheet.rpt**" and "**Form.rpt**" and I need to create one pdf out of them in Delphi.

Is there any way to merge two .rpts and export it into one pdf?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to create a container report and to add the 2 reports as subreports. This will work just in case you don't already have subreports in your existing reports. If you have subreports then the only option is to export both reports to separate PDFs and then join the 2 PDFs in one. BTW, there are some free tools that you can use to generate one PDF from multiple reports. Do you need to write this by yourself or external tools will work for you ?

Comment: thanks a ton for your quick reply. External tools will not work for me, so merging two pdfs using 3rd party tool is not an option. Good thing is I don't have subreports in my existing reports. So I would love to know more about your first option: **Create a container report and add the 2 reports as subreports**. But how would I achieve this in code?

Comment: This did not work:

    crpe.Subreports.Items[0].Clear;
    crpe.Subreports.Items[0].Name := 'Main.rpt';
    crpe.Subreports.Items[0].ParamFields[0].CurrentValue := empID;

    crpe.Subreports.Items[1].Clear;
    crpe.Subreports.Items[1].Name := 'Details.rpt';
    crpe.Subreports.Items[1].ParamFields[0].CurrentValue := empID;

    crpeEndorseForm.Output:=toExport;
    crpeEndorseForm.ExportOptions.Destination:=toApplication;     crpeEndorseForm.ExportOptions.FileName:='C:\EmployeeDetails.pdf';
crpeEndorseForm.ExportOptions.FileType:=AdobeAcrobatPDF;
crpeEndorseForm.Export;

Comment: You don't need to do this in code. In Crystal reports , create a new report and add a new subreport. In the subreport dialog choose to use an existing report and add the first of the reports, Do the same for the second report. You will need to define parameters and link them between teh main report and subreports but at the end you need to export just the main report

Comment: I would call that a master report. The problem here is my 2nd report is based on the employee ID, so my first report is always same, but second report changes depending on the type of employee. Initially I thought of creating a Master report with main report and then adding all possible details report and show or hide one of them depending on the employee type. But thats quite a task. I am looking for something simpler and manageable from Delphi.

Comment: You can add employee ID parameter to the master report and pass it down to the subreport